# I cant see statistics information for my auto-generated stats - is this normal? (SQL2005)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, statistics

I'm trying to diagnose a slow stored procedure (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476723/how-does-sql-server-work-out-the-estimated-number-of-rows)) and I've noticed that for my auto-generated stats (the ones named things like _WA_Sys_0000000A_0D0FEE32) I cant view the detailed histogram. If I click on the "Details" tab I just get the message:

```
No statistics information available.
```

If I click on the details tab for any of the statistics generated for my indexes then I can view the histogram just fine.

What does this mean?

- Is the histogram for auto-generated stats simply not available for viewing in this way?
- If this is the case is there any way to see / validate that these statistics are sensible
- Does this in fact mean that these statistics are not avaialble (as in, also not available to the query analyser)?

Comment: Is the table empty? That would explain the histogram not been there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sp_helpstats and DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS from a query window and you can see the distribution data.

[sp_helpstats (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173416.aspx)

[DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174384.aspx)